# Upload a picture to a table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, linux, png, ubuntu-16.04

I have mysql running on my Ubuntu 16.04 server.

I have a photo that I want to upload to a table in my mysql server (PNG file).

My photo is located on the server in both `/` and in /`var/lib/mysql-files with sufficient permissions`.

When I upload the pic to the table:

```
UPDATE photos SET photo = LOAD_FILE('/var/lib/mysql-files/file-name.png')
```

I get:

```
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

But then when I want to see the table itself:

```
SELECT picid,description,photo FROM photos WHERE picid = 1;
```

I get a long row of lines and then a ton of gibberish characters and weird things.

Want to know if it means that it worked or not.

Would check myself but it's a server that's in a private subnet in a VPC in AWS so it's a bit tricky to find out...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it sounds like your table update worked.

PNG files (and other image files such as JPG) are binary files, so they aren't readable when you view the file in something besides an image viewer program.